# Can't narrow simple TypeScript union type with undefined property

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, type-systems, union-types

I have two unioned types, one has a property and the other one hasn't. I assumed that checking for the existence of that property would allow me to narrow it down, but it isn't working.

I've created [this Playground repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20AuthenticatedProfile%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20userId%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20AnonymousProfile%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20userId%3A%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20otherProp%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20type%20Profile%20%3D%20AnonymousProfile%20%7C%20AuthenticatedProfile%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handleProfile(prof%3A%20Profile)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(prof.userId)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(prof.name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D). This other [very similar thing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20AuthenticatedProfile%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20userId%3A%20%2233%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0Aexport%20interface%20AnonymousProfile%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20userId%3A%20%2244%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20otherProp%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0Aexport%20type%20Profile%20%3D%20AnonymousProfile%20%7C%20AuthenticatedProfile%3B%0A%0Afunction%20handleProfile(prof%3A%20Profile)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(prof.userId%20%3D%3D%3D%20%2233%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(prof.name)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D) seems to work just fine. Am I using unions the wrong way?

Here's the code for the sake of completeness:

```
export interface AuthenticatedProfile {
    readonly userId: string;
    readonly name: string;
}
export interface AnonymousProfile {
    readonly userId: undefined;
    readonly otherProp: string;
}
export type Profile = AnonymousProfile | AuthenticatedProfile;

function handleProfile(prof: Profile) {
    if (prof.userId) {
        console.log(prof.name);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use type guards to restrict the type of the **prof** parameter.

```js
export interface AuthenticatedProfile {
    readonly userId: string;
    readonly name: string;
}
export interface AnonymousProfile {
    readonly userId: undefined;
    readonly otherProp: string;
}
export type Profile = AnonymousProfile | AuthenticatedProfile;

function isAuthenticatedProfile(prof: Profile): prof is AuthenticatedProfile {
    return (<AuthenticatedProfile>prof).name !== undefined;
}

function isAnonymousProfile(prof: Profile): prof is AnonymousProfile {
    return (<AnonymousProfile>prof).otherProp !== undefined;
}

function handleProfile(prof: Profile) {
    if (isAuthenticatedProfile(prof)) {
        console.log(prof.name);
    } else if (isAnonymousProfile(prof)) {
        console.log(prof.otherProp);
    }
}
```

You can read more about type guards in typescript in the Advanced Types section in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

Comment: Your solution looks good. I only have one question: if the property userId is part of both types and each type can only take a disjoint set of values, then why can't TypeScript infer the type after my original check?

Comment: for me calling `prof.userId` works just fine without any type guards.

Comment: It actually seems to be a known issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12600. Don't know why you don't see the error, it's right there in the playground repro that I posted

Comment: in that playground link accessing prof.userId works just fine. accessing prof.name gives the error. and that's fine because it's not in both types.

Comment: @MartínColl if this was the right answer please mark it as the correct one so other people seeing this question will know. :) If not please let me know what is missing.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
export interface AuthenticatedProfile {
    readonly type: "AuthenticatedProfile";
    readonly userId: string;
    readonly name: string;
}

export interface AnonymousProfile {
    readonly type: "AnonymousProfile";
    readonly userId: undefined;
    readonly otherProp: string;
}

export type Profile = AnonymousProfile | AuthenticatedProfile;

function handleProfile(prof: Profile) {
    if (prof.type === "AnonymousProfile") {
        console.log(prof.name); // Error
        console.log(prof.otherProp); // OK
        console.log(prof.userId); // OK
    }
    if (prof.type === "AuthenticatedProfile") {
        console.log(prof.name); // OK 
        console.log(prof.otherProp); // Error
        console.log(prof.userId); // OK
    }
}
```

Comment: It is good to know this alternative, but I'll stick with the other solution that does't change my values or types. But I have one question: if the property userId is part of both types and each type can only take a disjoint set of values, then why can't TypeScript infer the type after my original check?