# Typescript limit type combinations in class

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-2.5

I have a simple example:

```
interface IDog {
  bark: void;
  type: 'dog';
}
interface ICat {
  meow: void;
  type: 'cat';
}
type IAnimalType = 'cat' | 'dog';
type IAnimal = IDog | ICat;

class ContainsAnimal {
  animalType: IAnimalType;
  animal: IAnimal;

  sound() {
    if (this.animalType === 'dog') { this.animal.bark(); }
  }
}
```

This won't compile because the compiler doesn't know that `animalType === 'dog'` means that `type of animal === IDog` (and `bark` doesn't exist on `ICat`).

Is there a way I can limit class ContainsAnimal types so that `animal.type` and `animalType` always correspond to one another?

Comment: Take a look at type guards. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html. However, you should be cautious about doing things like this. Often it indicates a code smell. What is your ultimate goal? Why do you want to write code which somehow implies that a cat might somehow be able to bark?

Comment: This example might not be motivating enough; I don't see why you would store `animalType` at all.  If you check `this.animal.type` the compiler's control flow analysis does what you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't narrow simple TypeScript union type with undefined property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583342/cant-narrow-simple-typescript-union-type-with-undefined-property)

Comment: Based on the conversation beneath my (now-deleted) answer, it sounds as though @jcalz was right, and you need to provide us with an example that better reflects your use case.

Comment: `animal.type` is not available. After reconsidering I guess I could build what I want by adding more interfaces, eg. `IContainsDog` with `{ animalType: 'dog', animal: IDog }, same for Cat and then use type IContainsAnimal = IContainsDog | IContainsCat